# Regex match all hypens before colon and replace with uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

My current code

```js
var test = {
  'font-family-regular': 'Helvetica-Neue',
  'font-family-bold': 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold'
}

var styles = JSON.stringify(test);
styles = styles.replace(/(-.)/g, function(x) {
  return x[2].toUpperCase()
});
console.log(styles)
```

I have a requirement to match all hyphens before a colon and amend the preceding character to an uppercase

e.g.
    font-family-regular: 'Helvetica-Neue'

Should become: fontFamilyRegular: 'Helvetica-Neue'

The regex I have currently is replaces all hyphen including 'Helvetica-Neue'

```
text.replace(/(-.)/g, function(x){return x[1].toUpperCase()})
```

I want the above example to look like:

```
var test = {
  fontFamilyRegular: 'Helvetica-Neue',
  fontFamilyBold: 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold'
}
```

Comment: where is your code

Comment: So I am getting styles in a JSON format e.g 

    `var test = {
        font-family-regular: 'Helvetica-Neue',
        font-family-bold: 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold'
    }`

    `var styles = JSON.stringify(test)
    styles.replace(/(-.)/g, function(x){return x[2].toUpperCase()})`

I want it to look like:
    `var test = {
        fontFamilyRegular: 'Helvetica-Neue',
        fontFamilyBold: 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold'
    }`

Comment: First, you should escape the colon`/(-\.)/g`. Otherwise you will match  the hyphens and everything

Comment: `font-family-regular: --> font-Family-Fegular:` is not "matching all hyphens before a colon and amend the preceding character to an uppercase". If that's the desired result, then your explanation is misleading.

Comment: Assuming there is only 1 colon per line, you can use `-(.)(?=.*:)`. If there are spaces between the hyphens as your question currently displays, you can use `\s*-\s*(.)(?=.*:)`

Comment: my bad. It's more clear with the context.

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made. You need quotes around font-family-regular since you cannot have dashes in a JS var

Answer (score 2):

I would probably work on the two parts of the attribute independently:

```js
var text = "font-family-regular: 'Helvetica-Neue'";

var keyValue = text.split(':');

var result = keyValue
    .shift()
    .replace(/(-.)/g, function(x){
         return x[1].toUpperCase()
    }) + ':' + keyValue.join(' ');

alert(result);
```

Or with your updated question:

```js
var test = {
  'font-family-regular': 'Helvetica-Neue',
  'font-family-bold': 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold'
}

var style = {};
for (var key in test) {
    var newKey = key.replace(/(-.)/g, function(x) {
        return x[1].toUpperCase();
    });
    style[newKey] = test[key];
}

alert(JSON.stringify(style));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the keys and rename the keys directly.

```
Object.keys(test).forEach(function(item){ 
        var newItem = item.replace(/\s*-\s*./g, function(x){
               return x[x.length-1].toUpperCase();
        }); 
        test[newItem]=test[item];
        delete test[item];
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, based on the answers given I have managed to get this working.